# apt-get upgrade: Segmentation faulty tree... 50%

Tags: apt

I am getting

```
$sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Segmentation faulty tree... 50%
```

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clear the apt cache and try again

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
```

you can also remove the cached archives with

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Answer (score 2):

I (and my company) use ubuntu/linux mint exclusively on all of our systems -- production and workstations.  I upgrade ONLY when a new LTS comes out, if at all.  My backup server, for instance, (running a highly customized version of rsnapsnot) has not been upgraded for longer than its LTS was supported.  (if it ain't broke, don't fix it)  I say this just to add background to my answer.

I have a script which I run after I add a new repository and/or upgrade.  It keeps things fresh and unbroken.  I do a lot of funky things that are tuned to my own internal environment, but in a nutshell, this script does:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update && sudo apt list --upgradable
```

The answer by zakkak, which I upvoted as well, gives the first command -- which should, in fact, solve your issue.  I'm trying to put his answer into the context of my larger "solution."