# Segmentation faulty tree... 50% error when running sudo apt upgrade

Tags: apt, 18.04, upgrade, dependencies, segmentation-fault

My PC run Ubuntu 18.04, and it was only recently formatted and reinstalled.

When I run the command

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Segmentation faulty tree... 50%
```

The `sudo apt upgrade` command worked fine initially, but later it started showing a segmentation fault. Also there were some unmet dependencies errors while I tried to install gnome-extensions and Vim.

It was only after this, that `sudo apt upgrade` started showing the segmentation fault. Now while trying to download any application I am getting the same segmentation fault.

I did follow some ways to fix it (which worked for others who had the problem before me), but it doesn't seem to solve mine.

Here's the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214219/apt-get-upgrade-segmentation-faulty-tree-50) to what I tried. There were other answers, but I couldn't make much of it.

These are the other commands that give me a segmentation fault when I run them (`sudo apt-get update` works fine):

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Reading package lists... Done
Segmentation faulty tree... 50%
```

When I tried to install Vim:

```
sudo apt install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Segmentation faulty tree... 50%
```

Also when I run `sudo apt-get autoclean` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Segmentation faulty tree... 50%
```

Comment: How much Memory, how much swap? Do `free`. Read `man mkswap; man -a swapon`.

Comment: @waltinator
Here's the output:

                 total            used            free             shared      buff/cache   available   
Mem:        8051620     1378728     5061456      384240     1611436     6035016   
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148